# What does the number of papers presented in a conference say about the conference?

Tags: conference, ieee

If a conference 'C' has pushed 250 papers(per conference) to IEEE Xplore, and another conference 'B' has 65 papers (per conference) in IEEE Xplore digital libraries.
Does this mean Conference C is better than Conference B ? or is Conference B better than Conference C?

P.S. Both conference are sponsored by IEEE, and they both are in their 4th annual year.

Comment: No, it does not mean any of those things just because of number of papers.

Comment: It may be a good indicator of how many presentation rooms the conference has access to. Some venues are larger than others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Short answer:** It does not say anything!

**Longer answer:** Both the number of submitted papers and the number of accepted papers don't mean anything independently. There are topic-specific conferences and their communities are relatively small. Also, there are researchers -for a reason or another- who submit according to the location where the conference is held. All these reasons make it normal that some conferences don't receive a lot of submissions.

However, the ratio of the number of accepted papers to the number of submitted papers can be an indicator of the conference quality. It is actually used by a lot of conferences as a quality advertisement.

In the end, I wouldn't compare the conference 'C' against conference 'B' because this comparison is most of the time subjective. I would rather submit to a conference that has a good reputation and is well ranked (e.g. [core](http://portal.core.edu.au/conf-ranks/)) or has a good h-index (e.g. [google scholar](https://scholar.google.de/citations?view_op=top_venues&hl=en)).

Comment: Even the ratio may vary a lot based on the field. A highly popular field can have very low acceptance rates in top conferences, while a less popular field may have a higher rate due to there being fewer researchers working in it and self selection when submitting. The ratio is more useful to some extent when compared among different conferences for a given subject area.

Comment: @GoodDeeds I fully agree! there are even factors; for example, receiving a lot of bad quality papers or the opposite. I personally don't believe in these factors and I find only experience a factor to assess venues. Conference organizers usually use the ratio to give brief statistics and some times to advertise the quality of the conference.